# Print hello twice via Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am supposed to make this echo "hello" twice while only changing two things: fix the iterator so it increments each time, and set the while loop so it only runs twice. I'm a beginner so I'm not sure how to do this, really. Any suggestions?

```
var times = 0;
while ( ) {
  console.log( "hello" );
  times
};
```

Comment: Homework I assume? Please tag it as such.

Comment: As a hint, `times` is your iteration counter. You'll need to increment its value, and check in the `while` condition if it has met its maximum.

Comment: You can increment a variable in one of many ways, among which are `variable++;` (postfix increment, recommended), `++variable;` (prefix increment), `variable += 1;` (addition shorthand) and `variable = variable + 1;` (fully expanded)

Comment: *Please try something first!* (Read through the supplied handouts-texts, which should explain the general concept.)

Comment: And tagging as [tag:homework] because if it weren't, you'd use `console.log("hello"); console.log("hello");` ;)

Comment: There's a difference between "a beginner" and "someone who hasn't even looked up the basics of javascript".  I'll give you a hint: look for "variable", "condition", and "increment". This tutorial looks fairly good: http://www.echoecho.com/javascript.htm

Comment: Tell your instructor that a `for` loop is more appropriate in this case:  `for (var times = 0; times < 2; times++) { console.log("hello");}`

Comment: It's not really homework, I'm learning how to code online and I didn't know what to do for this, and I couldn't change much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`while` is a loop that takes an expression. *While* the expression is truthy (true for all intents and purposes), it will execute the code in the following statement or block.

So, how would you keep a counter for a loop? You want the counter to start at zero and go up to 2, then, once it reaches 2, it should stop. Suffice to say, you want to loop *while* your counter is less than 2, that is, `< 2`. So your expression is:

```
times < 2
```

and your loop is therefore:

```
while(times < 2) {
```

---

Now, you'll also need to increment your `times` variable so it goes up each time around the loop. There are a couple ways to do this. A nice and clear one should be:

```
times = times + 1;
```

But people usually contract it to `times += 1;`, or for incrementing by one:

```
times++;
```

So, your loop should end up as:

```
while(times < 2) {
    console.log("hello");
    times++;
}
```

Comment: +1: nice, clear explanation. Obviously _you_ know this minitech but the OP perhaps doesn't: an addition in the form `times = times + something` can be contracted to `times += something` (as compared to `times++` which increments by exactly 1).

Comment: @nnnnnn: Oops, forgot to include that. (See my comment, I made it into an answer.)

Answer (score 1):

The while loop's condition will check if `times` is less than 2. If it is, print hello and increment `times`.

```
var times = 0;
while (times < 2) { // 'times < 2' is the condition, what gets checked each iteration
  console.log( "hello" );
  times++; // set 'times' to 'times + 1'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way it could work

```
var times = 0;
while (times != 2) {
    console.log( "hello" );
    times = times + 1;
};
```

Computer scientists are anathema to this because `times != 2` is not tight enough for them. They claim `times < 2` is better. Although correct, this way makes more sense to non programmers because you are essentially saying "once you hit 2 stop!". Also `times++` is a shorthand version for `times = times + 1`